# Azure Website - Cannot Add wildcard ssl binding to my custom domain

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a wildcard ssl certificate and the azure web portal accepted the upload of my .pfx file fine...

[image: certificated]

I have added a custom domain fine as well and am able to save it fine as well before attempting to do what causes an error below:

[image]

When I try to link it to my custom domain:

[image]

And Save I get this error:

[image]

I have used this wildcard ssl certificate on all version of IIS fine...

it's from RapidSSL (GeoTrust signed) its 2048 bits

Anyone have this happen? does it not work with your own wildcard ssl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the new Preview Web portal (which looks awesome!) and it worked fine.. must be some sort of bug with the Site.